# Правило в htaccess для работы со слэшем на конце

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^tasks/(.*?)$ /system/modules/tasks/$1.php
```

http://site.ru/tasks/my - всё отлично

http://site.ru/tasks/my/ - 404 Not Found

Как сделать и поддержку слэша в конце?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ещё вариант

```
RewriteRule ^tasks/(.*?)/?$ /system/modules/tasks/$1.php
```

Comment: @istem, спасибо, выручили!

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteRule ^tasks/(.*?)/$
```

Можно еще чтобы работало со слэшем и без

```
RewriteRule ^tasks/(.*?)|/$
```